# How to use Russian letters inside custom environments?

Tags: unicode, utf8

I have created the following file

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\tcbset{
    codestyle/.style={width=0.9\textwidth,boxrule=0pt,colback=blue,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,left=0pt,right=0pt,boxsep=5pt,fontupper=\ttfamily, colupper=yellow}
}

\newtcblisting{code}{listing only, codestyle}

% Document
\begin{document}

    Пример кода:

    \begin{code}
        print("English comment"); // English comment
        print("Russian comment"); // Русский комментарий
    \end{code}

\end{document}
```

Encoding is UTF-8 without BOM, but I can add it with my editor (Jetbrains Idea).

Unfortunately, when I am trying to compile it, it draws Russian letter outside of `code` environment only.

[image]

Why and how to fix?

---

I have installed MiKTeX under Windows:

```
>where pdflatex
C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe

>pdflatex -version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.10 (MiKTeX 21.12)
© 1982 D. E. Knuth, © 1996-2021 Hàn Thế Thành
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019
compiled with curl version 7.72.0; using libcurl/7.72.0 Schannel
compiled with expat version 2.2.10; using expat_2.2.10
compiled with jpeg version 9.4
compiled with liblzma version 50020052; using 50020052
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 3.1.4; using LibreSSL 3.1.4
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.2.1; using 4.2.1
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 4.10; using 4.10
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 4.5; using 4.5
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.4
compiled with xpdf version 4.02
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

Comment: Hi, do not You want to use just \lstlisting and customize it with \lstset{}?

Comment: I don't know how to, please help!

Comment: Why not use `minted`? It's known that `listings` has very poor support for UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

The `tcolorbox` package uses `listings` by default, which does not work correctly with multibyte encodings. The `tcolorbox` allows you to specify a single-byte encoding that will be passed to the listing engine for processing: `listing utf8=cp1251`. Side effect - you also need to specify the language with the babel package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\tcbset{
    codestyle/.style={width=0.9\textwidth,boxrule=0pt,colback=blue,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,left=0pt,right=0pt,boxsep=5pt,fontupper=\ttfamily, colupper=yellow},
    listing utf8=cp1251
}

\newtcblisting{code}{listing only, codestyle}

% Document
\begin{document}

Пример кода:
\begin{code}
    print("English comment"); // English comment
    print("Russian comment"); // Русский комментарий
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have made fully customized file for You using `\lstlisting` it is easy to use then Your listing using `tcolorbox` (own thoughts)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\lstset{ keepspaces=true, 
backgroundcolor=\color{blue},  
showstringspaces=false,% for spaces between rus. words
language=C, 
extendedchars=\true,%for russian
framexrightmargin=0pt,
framexleftmargin=0pt,
framextopmargin=15pt,
framexbottommargin=15pt, 
frame=tb, framerule=0pt,
basicstyle=\color{yellow}\ttfamily\small}

\begin{lstlisting}
    print("English comment"); // English comment
    print("Russian comment"); // Русский комментарий
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```